# Emacs program to collapse Json to single line

Tags: json, emacs

I'm dealing with a file that has a list of single line json strings. To edit an individual json object, I found this tool: https://github.com/gongo/json-reformat. Now, I'm looking for the reverse operation: given a nicely formatted Json object, collapse it into a single string.

Emacs version: 24.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like `json-reformat` comes with anything for that.

Here's an interactive function that can do this:

```
(defun json-to-single-line (beg end)
  "Collapse prettified json in region between BEG and END to a single line"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (save-excursion
        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region beg end)
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (re-search-forward "\\s-+" nil t)
            (replace-match " "))))
    (print "This function operates on a region")))
```

Just evaluate the function definition -> highlight the json snippet you want reformatted -> and call this function interactively

Answer (score 4):

The standard `json` module that comes with current versions of emacs (since 24.4?) has a `json-pretty-print` function that normally wraps the JSON in a region, but when given a prefix argument minimizes it instead.

So, select the region containing the JSON to minimize and type, `C-u M-x json-pretty-print`.

This is better than the previous answers because it understands that whitespace inside strings should be untouched.

Comment: Sweet, this works very well

Answer (score 2):

The answers from @AesopHimself and @Henschkowski weren't quite right for me as they either didn't eliminate newlines or left double-spaces between elements when a newline and indent was condensed.  The `json-to-single-line` function with the regex below is what works for me:

```
(defun json-to-single-line (beg end)
  "Collapse prettified json in region between BEG and END to a single line"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (save-excursion
        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region beg end)
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (re-search-forward "[[:space:]\n]+" nil t)
            (replace-match " "))))
    (print "This function operates on a region")))
```

Answer (score 1):

For me (Emacs 25.1.1), lines in the region were not joined when using the accepted answer. To also remove line endings, I had to extend the regex:

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "\\s-+\\|\n" nil t)
  (replace-match " "))))
```